# ASP.NET passing variables from web form to code behind

Tags: asp.net, function, variables, webforms, behind

i'm developing a web application for my company, but i'm coming up against a very simple problem that i don't now how to resolve. I search a lot on internet but i can't find anything.
I need to call a code behind method from an asp.net controls passing variables.

This is the method in the code behind (file.aspx.cs):

```
protected void SayHello(object sender, EventArgs e, String RandomName)
{
  Response.Write(PrintedString);
 }
```

And this is a asp.net control that call the method through OnLoad event :

`<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hello" OnLoad="Visibility('ciao mamma')"></asp:Label>`

What's wrong with this simple thing? Where i'm wrong?

Please answer to this simple question, it's driving me crazy...Thanks.

Comment: Set the label text in page_load of your code-behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an argument to the event handler by the following way, but please note it will work for only asp button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click" OnCommand="btn_Command" CommandArgument="YourArgumentValue"/>
```

and then in the code behind file you do like this :

```
protected void btn_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

It will work for only asp button because they have a onCommand attribute with them.

whenever you will click on the button this code behind file code gets executed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was searching for. So i realize that i can't pass parameters in this way like in javascript:
`<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="SayHello(parameters)"/>`

Comment: @MattiaQuaglietta yes i think so, i tried in every way but failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value to label on `Page_Load` event

You can use below code.

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

`{`

```
   string UserName="test";
   Label1.Text="Hello "+ UserName;
```

`}`

Comment: @Slippery Pete Please click upvote or click 'correct' if above answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

Markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"><%=SayHello("foo") %></asp:Label>
```

Code behind:

```
protected string SayHello(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

Comment: No, i write an example. What I need is call a function passing a parameter value. I call a method with an event (for example OnLoad) with a parameter, like every programming language. In the code behind I do some operation with this parameter that I passed from the event in the web form (for example response.write(parameter)).

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here. I don't want set the label's value, i use it as example. I need to call a method through a event from the web form (file.aspx) to a method declared in the code behind (file.aspx.cs), passing custom parameter to the method.